# How to use Heroku-Scheduler

Tags: heroku, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, heroku-postgres

I've recently installed `https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler` in my heroku app, but I just cannot make any instruction get to work.

I think I don't know the correct syntax, for now I've tried with `heroku pgbackups:capture --expire --app running-app` command and selected frequency 10 mins.

It's been more than an hour and still hasn't done anything.

How can I get this to work?

Thanks

**EDIT:** This command is an example command, nor that I want to use that one specifically

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the pgbackups addon, https://addons.heroku.com/pgbackups which is scheduled for you based on the level you pick.

Heroku Scheduler is more for if you need to run a rack task within your application codebase.

UPDATE BASED ON REVISED QUESTION:

You would write a rake task (assuming your using Rails?) which you could run locally using `rake taskname` and to schedule it on Heroku you would enter `rake taskname` as the command in the scheduler page for them to execute it.